# repeat tracing records in web-api 2 owin self-hosted

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-web-api2, trace

I am writing web-api 2 OWIN-selfhosted console app( And i have one dll-library with ApiControllers and one dll with DataAccess types). I've added web-api tracing.

```
 public class dobStartUp
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver),new dobAssembliesResolver());
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IdobRDBRepository, dobRDBRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IResourcesContentRepository, AS3ContentRepository>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
            traceWriter.IsVerbose = false;
            traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Info;
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string baseAdress = "http://localhost:9001/";
            using(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<dobStartUp>(url: baseAdress))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Owin web-app host started");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to call my service via browser or client (VLC player or WinAmp) for streamcontent - everything goes right at first look. But when I look throuh trace records, I can find that every trace records goes twice.

```
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:9001/resources/buf/2, Message='http://localhost:9001/resources/buf/2'
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:9001/resources/buf/2, Message='http://localhost:9001/resources/buf/2'
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Resources', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Resources', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
'dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Projects\dobiji\sources\v2\dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost\bin\Release\MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\6.8.3.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='dobiji.WebApi.ResourcesController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='dobiji.WebApi.ResourcesController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='dobiji.WebApi.ResourcesController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='dobiji.WebApi.ResourcesController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetResourceById_buffered(Int32 id)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetResourceById_buffered(Int32 id)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'id' bound to the value '2'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
dobiji.WebApi.SimpleHost.vshost.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'id' bound to the value '2'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
```

Now I have only 2 ApiControllers with several methods. On every method from client tracing goes same way - dublicate trace records. 
I have not found any multi "registrations" in my code. Where it may be the reason of it?

Comment: Found double tracing registration in my code.So the question is not actual now. Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: have same issue. I'm completely green in all this. hope I'll find the double registration.